# Runtime Error After Inserting Variable Into Formula Statement

Tags: vba, formulas

Hellow All, the below original recorded statement works:

```
Dim lastrow, prodflow As String

lastrow = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row     'Determine last row where data ends

Range("G2:G" & lastrow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[-1],FIND(""-"",RC[-1],1)+4),'[Process Flows.xlsx]TABLE_X'!R1C1:R999C70,14,FALSE)"
```

However when I tried replacing TABLE_X with a variable prodflow, a runtime error occurs in my formula statement:

```
Dim lastrow, prodflow As String

lastrow = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row     'Determine last row where data ends
prodflow = Cells(2, 2)                      'Read value in cell B2 and store as string

Range("G2:G" & lastrow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[-1],FIND(""-"",RC[-1],1)+4),'[Process Flows.xlsx]" & prodflow & "'!R1C1:R999C70,14,FALSE)"
```

I have googled on the issue and all answers to similar questions point that what I am doing is correct. Is there anything else I am missing out? Thank you!

Comment: what is error number? what if you add `.value` to `prodflow = Cells(2, 2).value`. What value you find in **Immediate  window** if you add `Debug.Print prodflow` right after `prodflow = cells(....`?

Comment: extra suggestion- try to change `.Formula` into `.FormulaR1C1`

Answer (score 0):

try to build the formula string and then assign it to the range formula:

dim f = "=a + b"

RANGE. FORMULA = F

take the f result from the immidiate window and check it in excel...  if it works it should work in your code.